# Lenovo W530 Intel Core i7: VT enabled?

Tags: laptop, intel-core-i7, vt-x

Is Intel VT supported by this laptop/processor? I need it for a 64bit OS VM virtual machine?

If it is then my BIOS doesn't support it (no VT option under Config -> CPU). How to update my BIOS then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it uses the i7-3720QM processor then it does support VT. If it isn't working for you then you might have to change the bios settings. It should be under "Security | Virtualization" in your bios.

Comment: i7-3630QM support VT? Ran the Intel processor id utility.

Comment: The 3630 QM supports VT-x (but not VT-d). See [Ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/products/71459/Intel-Core-i7-3630QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz)

Comment: As Hennes says it supports VTx. Ark is great for finding out this type of information.

Answer (score 2):

VT support requires it to be supported in the:

- CPU
- Chipset
- BIOS

Just because the CPU lists support does not mean that it is a supported option from the notebook vendor. You can check with Lenovo support to ensure you have the latest BIOS installed and where the option is. My guess is that if it not there currently it will not be a supported option.